# Как связать TextBox.Text с свойством другого объекта (binding)

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Мне нужно в одном TextBox связать его свйоство Text с одним свойством из Settings. Т.е. при изменении TextBox.Text должно меняться поле в Settings и наоборот. Знаю точно что можно при помощи Binding'а сделать, однако... похоже настолько туп, что не могу найти элементарный гайд по байндингу. Пожалуйста, напишите простейший пример на основе моей задачи, только без наворотов, что-бы понять можно было даже мне :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Всё просто.

Если пространство имён по умолчанию вашего приложения — `MyApp`, ваши настройки обычно находятся в пространстве имён `MyApp.Settings`. Вам по идее нужен объект `MyApp.Settings.Default`. Пускай свойство называется `NumberOfDragons`. Тогда делаем вот как:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:settings="clr-namespace:MyApp.Properties"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Source={x:Static settings:Settings.Default},
                            Path=NumberOfDragons}"/>
</Window>
```

Что это означает?

1. Мы определили пространство имён `settings` для XAML, чтобы оно ссылалось туда, где лежат ваши `Settings`.
2. Мы в `Binding`'е указали объект, к которому происходит привязка: `Source={x:Static settings:Settings.Default}`. Это означает, что мы вызываем статический метод `Settings.Default`, и работаем с тем, что получили из него. (`Source` задаёт объект, к свойству которого мы привязываемся.)
3. Указываем само свойство: `Path=NumberOfDragons`. (`Path` задаёт свойство объекта, к которому мы привязываемся.)

Всё!

Не забудьте в конце работы приложения сказать `Settings.Default.Save();`.

---

В принципе, вы выбрали не самый лёгкий объект для `Binding`'а. Обычно привязываются не к какому-то статическому объекту, а к `DataContext`, в этом случае вам не надо указывать `Source`, оно подразумевается.

Ну и имя параметра `Path` (только этого параметра!) можно не указывать:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding NumberOfDragons, Source={x:Static settings:Settings.Default}}"/>
```

---

По поводу всяких продвинутых параметров `Binding`, вот есть краткая сводка (на английском): [Шпаргалка по WPF Binding](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/WpfBinding.pdf).

Comment: У меня вот так получилось: `<TextBox x:Name="textBoxScreenshotsFolder" Text="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Settings1.Default},Path=ScreenshotsFolder}"/>`
а пространство local уже автоматически объявлено
`xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ScreenShooter"`

Comment: @cyberdream: Ну это если у вас объект `Settings1` лежит в namespace'е `ScreenShooter`. Кстати, почему? Обычно Settings лежат в `ScreenShooter.Properties`.

Comment: Эмм, я даже не знаю, всегда так делал :)

Comment: @cyberdream: Может, вы поменяли свойства файла настроек или создали дополнительный.

Comment: Создал дополнительный, я раньше всегда так делал. Думал так правильно :) Кстати на ХэшКоде об этом узнал, видимо неправильно понял и дальше начал пользоваться этим не правильно

Comment: @cyberdream: По идее можно не создавать, C# делает для вас стандартный, если вы в свойствах проекта заходите во вкладку Settings.

Comment: я как раз это из вашего ответа и понял :) Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @cyberdream: Пожалуйста!